# DataGridView not visible on form Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, forms, datagridview

I had an issue with a DataGridView not being shown on a Form that was initialised from another Form on Windows 10 in Release mode. The issue is not present when debugging code in Debug Mode. I even tried turning off optimization.
It took me 2 days to work out the issue so im making this with the hope it helps someone else facing this issue as there it NOTHING online for this specific issue.

```
Scenario (Issue ONLY occurs in this scenario in Release built code)
Form1 - Click button to show Form2
Form2 - Has a DataGridView which is not loaded/shown on the form
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ColumnHeadersHeight` is set to anything other than default (21) on FormLoad then the DataGridView will not be shown on the form.

You can change the `ColumnHeadersHeight` property AFTER the form has loaded.

Comment: I am not sure that is correct. My tests show that you can make the column headers height anything four (4) and above if the grids `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` is set to `EnableResizing`. Can you show a reproducible example of this?